# Using REST to Send and Receive Complex Data

Tags: android, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

My client is an Android app and my service is an asp.net web api.  I’m the only one  using my service.  I am trying to duplicate, in the Android-REST world what I am already doing in the Microsoft Windows Phone 7/ WCF SOAP world.  I have numerous methods that both receive complex objects and return complex objects.

The WCF-SOAP world is simple.  You can pass any complex arguments you want and return any complex results you want.  Logically, it’s just a Remote Procedure Call.

But when I post questions about doing the same thing in REST, I’m told I should limit my services into GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE only.  And that I should only do what is “proper” according to RFC2616.  Some speak of this in almost a religious manner.

Forgeting about the religion, what’s wrong with using a GET for everything?  Or what’s wrong with using a POST for everything?  What I do does not fall into the simplistic RFC2616 categories.  For instance I’m passing a thousand legs of a trip taken in a car and I’m getting back another version of that trip with erratic GPS errors smoothed out.  Or, I’m sending a conversation in english and getting that conversation back in German.

In the android client I have the objects I want to send over HTTP already serialized into json strings by using Google-GSON.  So my questions are…

How can I send these json strings to my REST Service as arguments in either GET or POST?

Is it possible and feasible to use just all GETs (or all POSTs) for all of my calls to my REST Service and how do I do that?

I have a more pragmatic question about this posted at [sending a json string in a http url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592928/sending-a-json-string-in-a-http-url) as I can’t find any examples anywhere of sending json strings over http GET or POST.

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 1):

Using the good HTTP verb is very usefull to simply know what to do when you request failed (for example) or just to do some specific stuff. If you sent a POST request, it's implicitly suppose that you have to parse your resource in order to obtain a stream which be sent via the request's body. In other hand, when you are retrieving data via GET, it's suppose that the request is gonna be sent back to you as a stream that you will mapped to your model, pojo, or anything else.

I can suggest you to use library such as [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid).  You can send POJO and receive POJO. It's a "resource oriented" library, so you can know at any moment if a particular local resource is remotely syncronized. Data persistence between local and remote is automatically handles.

RESTDroid is alpha released. You can have a look to [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). It's a powerful library to manage REST call but it's up to you to manage the persistency between local and remote resources.

Answer (score 0):

1) The WCF-SOAP world is simple. You can pass any complex arguments you want and return any complex results you want. Logically, it’s just a Remote Procedure Call.
- IN REST:"You can pass any complex arguments you want and return any complex results you want too.

2a) Forgeting about the religion, what’s wrong with using a GET for everything?
In SOAP services WCF/or classical you are wrapping all requests into http POST so using single verb would end up to SOAP or - don't even think about it - your own communication protocol:-D

2b) You can technically compose GET request with non empty body - most of the servers ignore it by default though and it would be technically problematic to read it..

the other part of the question is answered by [Pcriulan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836434/pcriulan) above